# Nginx(HTTPS) upstream SpringBoot(http) after success logon chrome redirect to HTTP

Tags: spring-boot, nginx

SpringBoot App started on 8080

Nginx incoming request on :443 proxy to :8080

start page is ok on https://site/ but
after login in SpringBoot chrome redirect to http://site/ (not to https://site/) WHY??? how to FIX

> Request URL: https://site/login
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Status Code: 302
>
> Remote Address: 85.26.149.68:443
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> RESPONSE HEADERS
>
> HTTP/1.1 302
>
> Server: nginx/1.14.0
>
> Date: Mon, 25 Feb 2019 11:40:17 GMT
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5196D2D1A7A681BBF713BD3AF61F14FF; Path=/; HttpOnly
>
> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>
> Pragma: no-cache
>
> Expires: 0
>
> X-Frame-Options: DENY
>
> Location: http://site/

And Chrome redirect on after login page page http://site/  WHY ?????

```
upstream spring_boot_srv {
    server localhost:8080 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
   listen         80;
   server_name    site;
   return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name site;
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_certificate_key /media/some.key;
    ssl_certificate /media/some.crt;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$proxy_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_connect_timeout      240;
        proxy_send_timeout         240;
        proxy_read_timeout         240;
        proxy_pass http://spring_boot_srv;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below entry in your `application.properties`

```
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

[For more info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https)